# Pandas Merge and Complete rows with same id

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop

Here is an extract of my dataframe :

| ID | LU | MA | ME | JE | VE | SA | DI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | B |  | B | B |  |  |  |
| 201 | C | C | C | C | C |  |  |
| 211 | A |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 211 |  | D | D | D |  |  |  |
| 211 |  |  |  |  | B |  |  |
| 213 |  |  |  |  |  | A | A |
| 216 | K | K | K | K |  |  |  |
| 216 |  |  |  |  | K |  |  |
| 217 | B | B | B | B | B |  |  |

I have some rows with same `ID` and want to "merge" them into only one row while completing them.
Here is an example of what I want to have as a result :

| ID | LU | MA | ME | JE | VE | SA | DI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | B |  | B | B |  |  |  |
| 201 | C | C | C | C | C |  |  |
| 211 | A | D | D | D | B |  |  |
| 213 |  |  |  |  |  | A | A |
| 216 | K | K | K | K | K |  |  |
| 217 | B | B | B | B | B |  |  |

I'm new to pandas dataframes and have try to use `drop_duplicates` method but I need something different because of the restriction on `keep` parameters.
Also the dataframe is sorted by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one non empty value per groups use:

```
df = df.replace('',np.nan).groupby('ID', as_index=False).first().fillna('')
```

If possible multiple values and need unique values in original order use lambda function:

```
print (df)
    ID LU MA ME JE VE SA DI
0  201  B     C  B         
1  201  C  C  C  B  C    


f = lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x.dropna()).keys())
df = df.replace('',np.nan).groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(f)
print (df)
    ID   LU MA ME JE VE SA DI
0  201  B,C  C  C  B  C
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be treated as a pivot.  You'd need to melt the df first then pivot:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='ID')
   .dropna()
   .pivot(index='ID',columns='variable',values='value')
   .fillna('')
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
   .reset_index()
)
```